# Serve video file to iPhone from ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: iphone, asp.net-mvc, video-streaming

I'm attempting to serve video files from ASP.NET MVC to iPhone clients. The video is formatted properly, and if I have it in a publicly accessible web directory it works fine.

The core issue from what I've read is that the iPhone requires you to have a resume-ready download environment that lets you filter your byte ranges through HTTP headers. I assume this is so that users can skip forward through videos.

When serving files with MVC, these headers do not exist. I've tried to emulate it, but with no luck. We have IIS6 here and I'm unable to do many header manipulations at all. ASP.NET will complain at me saying "***This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.***"

Upgrading isn't an option, and I'm not allowed to move the files to a public web share. I feel limited by our environment but I'm looking for solutions nonetheless.

Here is some sample code of what I'm trying to do in short...

```
public ActionResult Mobile(string guid = "x")
{
    guid = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(guid);
    apMedia media = DB.apMedia_GetMediaByFilename(guid);
    string mediaPath = Path.Combine(Transcode.Swap_MobileDirectory, guid + ".m4v");

    if (!Directory.Exists(Transcode.Swap_MobileDirectory)) //Make sure it's there...
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Transcode.Swap_MobileDirectory);

    if(System.IO.File.Exists(mediaPath))
        return base.File(mediaPath, "video/x-m4v");

    return Redirect("~/Error/404");
}
```

I know that I need to do something like this, however I'm unable to do it in .NET MVC. http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Range-Specific-Requests-in-ASP-NET.aspx

Here is an example of an HTTP response header that works:

```
Date    Mon, 08 Nov 2010 17:02:38 GMT
Server  Apache
Last-Modified   Mon, 08 Nov 2010 17:02:13 GMT
Etag    "14e78b2-295eff-4cd82d15"
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Content-Length  2711295
Content-Range   bytes 0-2711294/2711295
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/plain
```

And here is an example of one that doesn't (this is from .NET)

```
Server  ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date    Mon, 08 Nov 2010 18:26:17 GMT
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version 2.0
Content-Range   bytes 0-2711294/2711295
Cache-Control   private
Content-Type    video/x-m4v
Content-Length  2711295
Connection  Close
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

UPDATE: This is now a [project on CodePlex](http://mediastreamingmvc.codeplex.com/).

Okay, I got it working on my local testing station and I can stream videos to my iPad. It's a bit dirty because it was a little more difficult than I expected and now that it's working I don't have the time to clean it up at the moment. Key parts:

Action Filter:

```
public class ByteRangeRequest : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    protected string RangeStart { get; set; }
    protected string RangeEnd { get; set; }

    public ByteRangeRequest(string RangeStartParameter, string RangeEndParameter)
    {
        RangeStart = RangeStartParameter;
        RangeEnd = RangeEndParameter;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");

        if (!filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(RangeStart))
            filterContext.ActionParameters.Add(RangeStart, null);
        if (!filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(RangeEnd))
            filterContext.ActionParameters.Add(RangeEnd, null);

        var headerKeys = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Where(key => key.Equals("Range", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        Regex rangeParser = new Regex(@"(\d+)-(\d+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        foreach(string headerKey in headerKeys)
        {
            string value = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers[headerKey];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                if (rangeParser.IsMatch(value))
                {
                    Match match = rangeParser.Match(value);

                    filterContext.ActionParameters[RangeStart] = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].ToString());
                    filterContext.ActionParameters[RangeEnd] = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].ToString());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    }
}
```

Custom Result based on FileStreamResult:

```
public class ContentRangeResult : FileStreamResult
{
    public int StartIndex { get; set; }
    public int EndIndex { get; set; }
    public long TotalSize { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

    public FileStreamResult(int startIndex, int endIndex, long totalSize, DateTime lastModified, string contentType, Stream fileStream)
        : base(fileStream, contentType)
    {
        StartIndex = startIndex;
        EndIndex = endIndex;
        TotalSize = totalSize;
        LastModified = lastModified;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = this.ContentType;
        response.AddHeader(HttpWorkerRequest.GetKnownResponseHeaderName(HttpWorkerRequest.HeaderContentRange), string.Format("bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", StartIndex, EndIndex, TotalSize));
        response.StatusCode = 206;

        WriteFile(response);
    }

    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        Stream outputStream = response.OutputStream;
        using (this.FileStream)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
            int totalToSend = EndIndex - StartIndex;
            int bytesRemaining = totalToSend;
            int count = 0;

            FileStream.Seek(StartIndex, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            while (bytesRemaining > 0)
            {
                if (bytesRemaining <= buffer.Length)
                    count = FileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesRemaining);
                else
                    count = FileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                bytesRemaining -= count;
            }
        }
    }      
}
```

My MVC action:

```
[ByteRangeRequest("StartByte", "EndByte")]
public FileStreamResult NextSegment(int? StartByte, int? EndByte)
{
    FileStream contentFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\temp\Gets.mp4");
    var time = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\temp\Gets.mp4");
    if (StartByte.HasValue && EndByte.HasValue)
        return new ContentRangeResult(StartByte.Value, EndByte.Value, contentFileStream.Length, time, "video/x-m4v", contentFileStream);

    return new ContentRangeResult(0, (int)contentFileStream.Length, contentFileStream.Length, time, "video/x-m4v", contentFileStream);
}
```

I really hope this helps. I spent a LOT of time on this! One thing you might want to try is removing pieces until it breaks again. It would be nice to see if the ETag stuff, modified date, etc. could be removed. I just don't have the time at the moment.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for all your awesome help. I will test this in the morning!

Comment: You kick ass, man, this works just like it should. For everyone's reference, I watched the iPhone request headers as it streamed the video. It makes many subsequent requests asking for small, specific byte ranges as it progresses through the video. I assume it pieces them all together on the fly. Thanks for all of your help Erik.

Comment: Also, forgot to mention this, but I had to change "public class FileStreamResult : FileStreamResult" back to "public class ContentRangeResult : FileStreamResult". It didn't like me extending a class with the same name! Just a minor issue for your editing.

Comment: It was a typo. Sorry. After I worked it all up and got it working I re-implemented it cleanly in a new environment to do a blog post on it and picked different names. I manually edited the names when I posted the updated source but it was late and I obviously messed up! Glad it's working for you. The blog post I wrote: https://vikingerik.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/ios-media-streaming-for-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: I'm not sure if you're still interested but I've refined the solution and put it up on CodePlex. I think it's a little cleaner and makes using it on your actions a bit easier. There are two projects, the library and a demo MVC application that streams media to iOS devices. http://mediastreamingmvc.codeplex.com/

Comment: I started having problems with my iPhone videos. I'm not sure why but I have made additional tweaks as well. I'll see what I have against yours. Maybe we can collaborate on the final version?

Comment: Sure! I'm not using the code in a real environment so I didn't have good usage scenarios for testing. I'd appreciate any help or input. Let me know if you're interested in contributing to the CodePlex edition or whatever you want to do.

Comment: This code is really solid, I just don't know what's wrong with my server. If I use a resumable download extension on Firefox or something the files come out binary equivalent. The iPhone still messes up somewhere along the line though. It's saying that the media file format isn't supported, but if I access it directly through an Apache server or something it works. Perhaps its the content types?

Answer (score 2):

I tried looking for an existing extension but I didn't immediately find one (maybe my search-fu is weak.)

My immediate thought is that you'll need to make two new classes.

First, create a class inheriting from `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`. This is the same base class for `HttpGet`, `HttpPost`, etc. In this class you'll override `IsValidForRequest`. In that method, examine the headers to see if a range was requested. You can now use this attribute to decorate a method in your controller which will get called when someone is requested part of a stream (iOS, Silverlight, etc.)

Second, create a class inheriting from either `ActionResult` or maybe `FileResult` and override the `ExecuteResult` method  to add the headers you identified for the byte range that you'll be returning. Return it like you would a JSON object with parameters for the byte range start, end, total size so it can generate the response headers correctly.

Take a look at the way `FileContentResult` is implemented to see how you access the context's `HttpResponse` object to alter the headers.

Take a look at `HttpGet` to see how it implements the check for `IsValidForRequest`. The source is available on CodePlex or you can use Reflector like I just did.

You might use this info to do a little more searching and see if anyone has already created this custom `ActionResult` already.

For reference, here is what the AcceptVerbs attribute looks like:

```
public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
    if (controllerContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
    }
    string httpMethodOverride = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.GetHttpMethodOverride();
    return this.Verbs.Contains<string>(httpMethodOverride, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

And here is what FileResult looks like. Notice the use of AddHeader:

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    }
    HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
    response.ContentType = this.ContentType;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FileDownloadName))
    {
        string headerValue = ContentDispositionUtil.GetHeaderValue(this.FileDownloadName);
        context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", headerValue);
    }
    this.WriteFile(response);
}
```

I just pieced this together. I don't know if it will suit your needs (or works).

```
public class ContentRangeResult : FileStreamResult
{
    public int StartIndex { get; set; }
    public int EndIndex { get; set; }
    public int TotalSize { get; set; }

    public ContentRangeResult(int startIndex, int endIndex, string contentType, Stream fileStream)
        :base(fileStream, contentType)
    {
        StartIndex = startIndex;
        EndIndex = endIndex;
        TotalSize = endIndex - startIndex;
    }

    public ContentRangeResult(int startIndex, int endIndex, string contentType, string fileDownloadName, Stream fileStream)
        : base(fileStream, contentType)
    {
        StartIndex = startIndex;
        EndIndex = endIndex;
        TotalSize = endIndex - startIndex;
        FileDownloadName = fileDownloadName;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FileDownloadName))
        {
            System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition() { FileName = FileDownloadName };
            context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
        }

        context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", string.Format("bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", StartIndex, EndIndex, TotalSize));
        //Any other headers?


        this.WriteFile(response);
    }

    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        Stream outputStream = response.OutputStream;
        using (this.FileStream)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
            int totalToSend = EndIndex - StartIndex;
            int bytesRemaining = totalToSend;
            int count = 0;

            while (bytesRemaining > 0)
            {
                if (bytesRemaining <= buffer.Length)
                    count = FileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesRemaining);
                else
                    count = FileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);

                bytesRemaining -= count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
return new ContentRangeResult(50, 100, "video/x-m4v", "SomeOptionalFileName", contentFileStream);
```

Comment: I tried to append a header for "Accept-Requests: bytes" but .NET is either refusing to add it or ignoring it. I can't get it to show up when I output my response. It's kind of a critical piece to have, do you have ideas on how to force it?

Comment: I just posted some code snippets pulled from reflector. The second one uses the AddHeader method on the context. Is this how you're doing it? If you're not modified the context's copy of the response, it probably won't persist which is why I recommend creating your own return type here (rather than trying to add the headers to another return type like FileContentResult).

Comment: Looking at the link you provided, it seems like things should run like this: Decorate your download action to see if a byte range was requested. Examine the request object to get the range requested during your response. In the response, add the header that you accept bytes regardless if the client has requested it. Also include headers about the range provided (hopefully based on what was requested.) Looking at existing objects in the MVC 2 framework, this should all work. In your response type are you using AddHeader? Does it throw an error? Does the header actually appear in the response?

Comment: You probably won't care if they send a range request before picking your controller method to execute. If not, don't inherit from ActionMethodSelectorAttribute and instead implement IActionFilter or inherit from ActionFilter which will give you ActionExecutingContext where you can examine your request and see if a range was requested. You can pass the value into your controller method as a parameter as if it was submitted from a form that way.

Comment: If you still haven't gotten it working, let me know. I grabbed a video from YouTube that I can view on my iPad, put together some stuff and I'm able to successfully stream it to my iPad using MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Can you move outside of MVC? This is a case where the system abstractions are shooting you in the foot, but a plain jane IHttpHandler should have alot more options.

All that said, before you implement your own streaming server, you are probably better off buying or renting one . . .

Comment: We have a streaming server... Our admins will never get it setup right before I need this done. I'm stuck with MVC for now.

Answer (score -1):

The header that work have the Content-type set to text/plain, is that correct or is a typo?.
Anyone, you can try to set this headers on the Action with:

```
Response.Headers.Add(...)
```

Comment: Response.Headers.Add does not work in IIS6 because of the error I cited above. I think it just ignores the test/plain which is why it still works.

Comment: Looking in Reflector there looks like there is a specific method in Reponse called AddHeader - it seems odd to me this would be there if headers were immutable. In addition, other response types modified content type and encoding and they work on IIS 6 (though they access specific functions rather than modify the Headers property directly).

Comment: I believe Response.AppendHeader(string,string) works. I don't have any other control over it though.